# How to set PTY (Pseudo Terminal) to NON-ECHOING Unix in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, unix, nonblocking, pty

I‘ve successfully implemented a PTY (Pseudo Terminal) Function: master and slave which successfully communicate. But often when I read data from the slave, it appears to be echoing.
Is there any way how to disable this ?
After some research I found out, that this is possible changing the flags of the termios struct:

```
StructTermios.c_lflag = 0;
```

Unfortunately I didn‘t manage to disable echo in the PTY ()

Is there any way to do so, any ideas, suggestions, proposals, websites ... ?

I would love to hear from you ❤️,

Regards, from Brooks (~)

Comment: Are you using ncurses?

Comment: @Eljay Actually not